# How to find unique record from table in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is my method have written in Implementclasss for getting unique AlbumName from table..

```
      public static List<CRBT_Promotion> getalbumformis()
        {
            List<CRBT_Promotion> misalbum = new List<CRBT_Promotion>();
            using (crbt_onwebEntities dbcontext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
            {
                misalbum = (from z in dbcontext.CRBT_Promotion select z).Distinct().ToList();
            }
            return misalbum;
        }
```

and below in my action have written in controller to get unique albumname and I have to call my method ahich has beeen defined in implement class as above. please help me

```
  public ActionResult MISAlbum()
        {
            AlbumSongModel s = new AlbumSongModel();
            List<CRBT_Promotion> lst = implement.getalbumformis();
            s.albums = lst.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.AlbumName.ToString(),
                Text = x.AlbumName
            });            
            return View("MISAlbum",s);
        }
```

In my table AlbumName column has duplicate entry and I have to fetch only unique AlbumNAme from table.

Comment: Perhaps you should let everyone know what you have already tried versus scream "ITS NOT WORKING".  Civility goes a long way versus screaming.

Comment: Hello sir....  I have tried it and its not working as per our requirements. Please give me some another code if possible

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work try it out.

```
public static List<CRBT_Promotion> getalbumformis()
        {
            List<CRBT_Promotion> misalbum = new List<CRBT_Promotion>();
            using (crbt_onwebEntities dbcontext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
            {
                 misalbum = from z in dbcontext.CRBT_Promotion   
                .GroupBy(p => new CRBT_Promotion {p.AlbumName} )
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList(); 
            }
            return misalbum;
        }

public ActionResult MISAlbum()
        {
            AlbumSongModel s = new AlbumSongModel();
            s.albums = implement.getalbumformis();
            return View("MISAlbum",s);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the album object in your first method, you need **DistinctBy** which isn't part of the .net libraries.

However you could first select the unique album name by using this query:

```
misalbum = (from z in dbcontext.CRBT_Promotion select z.AlbumName).Distinct().ToList();
```

This will return a list of all distinct album names, then from there you can do what you want with the names, maybe go back to the db and retrieve the objects in your controller or in the same method

Comment: In case you didn't see, in your query you are selecting distinct objects, the one i posted is selecting distinct album names

Comment: Hello Sir...  I have tried as you have given me code. But in this case I getting error that Error 22 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<mvclogin.Models.CRBT_Promotion>'

Comment: Change the type of misalbum to List<String> and the return type of the function to List<String> then you will have a collection of unique album names. From that list you can get the objects from the db

Comment: Thank you so much....This is the code I have used and its working properly  public static List<CRBT_Promotion> getalbumformis()
        {
            List<CRBT_Promotion> misalbum = new List<CRBT_Promotion>();
            using (crbt_onwebEntities dbcontext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
            {
               misalbum = (from z in dbcontext.CRBT_Promotion.GroupBy(p=>p.AlbumName).Select(g=>g.FirstOrDefault()) select z).ToList();
            }
            return misalbum;
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static List<CRBT_Promotion> getalbumformis()
        {
            List<CRBT_Promotion> misalbum = new List<CRBT_Promotion>();
            using (crbt_onwebEntities dbcontext = new crbt_onwebEntities())
            {
               misalbum = (from z in dbcontext.CRBT_Promotion.GroupBy(p=>p.AlbumName).Select(g=>g.FirstOrDefault()) select z).ToList();
            }
            return misalbum;
        }
```

Its working.. I have used it